What are the actual parameters to be encoded?
lib/main.dart:860:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'builder'.
        builder: (BuildContext ctx) => Container(
        ^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_map-6.1.0/lib/src/layer/marker_layer.dart:60:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const Marker({
        ^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:938:15: Error: No named parameter with the name 'onPlacePicked'.
              onPlacePicked: (location) {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/open_street_map_search_and_pick-0.1.1/lib/open_street_map_search_and_pick.dart:31:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const OpenStreetMapSearchAndPick({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:923:22: Error: The argument type 'void Function(LatLng)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapPosition, LatLng)?'.


'LatLng' is from 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/latlong2-0.9.1/lib/latlong.dart').
'TapPosition' is from 'package:flutter_map/src/gestures/positioned_tap_detector_2.dart' ('/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_map-6.1.0/lib/src/gestures/positioned_tap_detector_2.dart').
onTap: _handleTap, // Handle tap on map
^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.


Process 'command 'D:\app\sggsapp\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I tried many alter parameters but not working. Please help me i have used the plugins flutter_map and open_street_map_search_and_pick.

Can you please include a [mcve]? What exactly are you doing? Can you show your build configuration?

Try to use the as keyword in your imports. He seems not to know which library they come from.
